# Upgraded to Laravel 5.3 from 5.2 and authorisation just won't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have upgraded to Laravel 5.3 and authorisation fails, login just returns me to the login box even for valid user. My old Authenticate.php middleware never gets called. I have changed to middleware groups in kernel.php. I have split the old auth controllers out into the new ones.

My code is a bit too long and complex to post here.

I wondered if there were any tricks or tips to be aware of here please?

Comment: What are the steps you've taken during the upgrade process?

Comment: I used Laravel Shift and then went through and did all the manual changes in the upgrade guide. Where I have got confused is with Auth which perhaps has changed but I am not sure. I just cannot get past the login.

Comment: See my own solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it after a lot of experimentation. The main issue is the upgrade had replaced in kernel.php my middleware Authenticate.php with the vanilla illuminate\middleware\authenticate.php. There were some little side issues as well but this is the one that was the real issue.